# Retrieving data from GORM Raw() Query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to learn Golang via project based learning. The problem I have placed before myself to simulate customers adding products to their cart. Currently, I have the `Cart.go` model as such..

```
type Cart struct {
     ID         string    
     Customer   Customer  
     CustomerID string    
     Product    Product   
     ProductID  string    
     CreatedAt  time.Time 
     UpdatedAt  time.Time
}
```

On the Cart model, I have a function defined as

```
func (c *Cart) GetAllItemsInCart(db *gorm.DB, customer_id string) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    items := db.Raw("SELECT id, product_id FROM carts WHERE customer_id = ?", customer_id).Scan(&c)

    return items, nil
}
```

This function is called in a controller

```
func (server *Server) GetAllCartItems(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)

    id := vars["id"]

    cart := models.Cart{}

    items, err := cart.GetAllItemsInCart(server.DB, id)

    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    responses.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, items)
}
```

As I understand it currently is that `Scan()` will scan the value of a struct, or in this case load the data found into the specified struct. However, the response I am seeing come back is

```
 {
    "Value": null,
    "Error": null,
    "RowsAffected": 2
 }
```

Which gives me 50% hope because "RowsAffected": 2 would be correct. However, the payload response is obviously not what I am looking for. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use `Scan(c)`, `c` is already a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to fix a couple of things:

- You will need to use `Scan(c)` instead of `Scan(&c)` since `c` is already a pointer.
- You should always check for errors. In your `GetAllItemsInCart` method, you don't pass or check the error. Technically, you do pass it (inside the `items` object), but you do not check it anywhere.
- There is no need to pass the `*gorm.DB` pointer higher up.

If you want to preserve the structure of the code the way you already started, it could look something like this:

```
func (c *Cart) GetAllItemsInCart(db *gorm.DB, customer_id string) error {
    return db.Raw("SELECT id, product_id FROM carts WHERE customer_id = ?", customer_id).Scan(c).Error
}

// controller
func (server *Server) GetAllCartItems(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)

    id := vars["id"]

    cart := models.Cart{}

    err := cart.GetAllItemsInCart(server.DB, id)
    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    responses.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, cart)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

`Scan` places the value into the pointer to a variable you've given it (`via &c`), and returns a database transaction object. You're calling that transaction object `items`, which it isn't. The items (ie, the contents of your cart) are in `c *Cart`, not in the thing returned by `Scan`.

Your method modifies `c` by filling it, it doesn't have to return anything, unless you want to return the error that `Scan` may return.

Instead of this...

```
    items, err := cart.GetAllItemsInCart(server.DB, id)

    // ... 

    responses.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, items)
```

You should be doing this:

```
    err := cart.GetAllItemsInCart(server.DB, id)

    // ...

    responses.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, cart)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and insight, I really appreciate it!